# We have to get this release out the door

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-combination

What does the line **We have to get this release out the door** means. Did that mean to complete a task by EOD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting something "out the door" is a very common expression among people working in the field of computers.

It means to bring any development task to a stage where it can be delivered to the customer for sale.

**We have to get this release out the door** would imply that the release is to be finished. However, the sentence itself does not say anything about the time frame.

Answer (score 0):

Get it out the door in this context means to release it. Also, EOD in this context stands for "end of the day", you might also hear COB which means the same thing and it stands for "close of the business day".